# Pushing noncredit card transaction to Square

Tags: square, square-connect

Using the square connect api, I'd like to simply add an order to a location's "balance" without charging a card. The goal is to add grubhub and other non-square transactions to a square account.

The orders api seems to simply return an Order object meant to be used in a transaction in which a credit card would be charged. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot create transactions via the API without charging a card. You can create cash transactions with the Point Of Sale app and that will probably have the effect you want.

Comment: That's what I feared. It looks like with the POS api, you still have to manually acknowledge the transaction in the square app, which opens automatically when the transaction is made. Are you aware of a workaround for this?

Comment: No, there is not a fully automated way to do cash payments at this time